# Why do we must write a target in container when load component dynamically in angular2?

Tags: angular

I'm using angular2(v2.2.4) to build my web app. In this app I need to load components dynamically. I have read nearly all the relative answers in stackoverflow and found a depressing fact: we need write a target element in the container to load our component like this as below:

`<div #target></div>`

Then we use it in the container component ts code like this:

`@ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vcRef: ViewContainerRef;`

In the end, the container of the dynamically loaded component has the ugly additional element `<div _ngcontent-mbk-0></div>` in the dom.

Here comes the question: why angular2 do not need the target element when we write all components statically in ts files? Do we have any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html

> To access a ViewContainerRef of an Element, you can either place a
>   Directive injected with ViewContainerRef on the Element, or you obtain
>   it via a ViewChild query.

You can also use `ng-container` or `template` instead of `div` to get reference to `ViewContainerRef`. These tags are not plaсed in `DOM`

Comment: Thx for your help. I think I can solve my problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 is built to support ahead of time compilation.
What you write into a components template becomes generated JavaScript where it makes sense.
For dynamically added components Angular2 needs an anchor that it can generate some hook that can be used to place the dynamic component.

Angular2 is built in a way that it can be rendered on other technologies than HTML and therefore added some abstraction wherever it is necessary to read from the DOM.

Comment: Thx for your explain. I know you mean angular2 use a different way to render statically component written in ts files, right? In dynamical loading case Angular2 can not  use the same way so the target element is essential, right?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean with your comment. A common misconception is that Angular2 takes a components template and adds it to the DOM and then looks up bindings `()`, `[]`, ` {{}}` and assigns values and event handlers, but that's not how Angular2 works. In Angular2 components templates are processed (compiled) by Angular2 and only the compiled result is actually added to the DOM.